# Python multiprocessing pool get integer identifying call

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing

    def func():
        # Print call index
        pass

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    p.map(func, data)
```

In the above code, is it possible to print in func(), an integer identifying the number of times it has been called 0, 1...

I want to do this because there is some code in func() which I only want to execute once, and it cannot be moved outside of func()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do involves sharing state between processes -- which can get to be very hairy in Python. If you don't think you can restructure your program to avoid it, `multiprocessing` has most of the useful synchronization constructs from the `threading` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes. It sounds like maybe you need a lock and some shared memory.